# Convert a Time.now to the exact hours on the first Unix Day

Tags: ruby

I have a `Time.now` object. I would like to create a new day on the first UNIX day with the same amount of hours, minutes and seconds as the provided `Time.now` object has.

Is there a way to do this automatically? Or do you have to manually copy the minutes/seconds.

Comment: In which Timezone do you want the result? UTC or local Timezone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It calculates the time between now and last midnight, and adds it to Unix epoch.

```
require 'date'
now = Time.now
Time.at(now-now.to_date.to_time)
```

Thanks Stefan and steenslag for the insightful comments.

Comment: `Time.at(Time.now-Date.today.to_time)` is the same, but shorter.

Comment: You should always refer to the same instance, i.e. `t = Time.now; Time.at(t - t.to_date.to_time)`.

Comment: Assuming you have active support, you can simplify it further using `Time#seconds_since_midnight`.

Comment: Fun fact : every answer yet gives a different result, depending on the local timezone.

Comment: @Stefan Why? in case Time.now and Date.today are calculated in two different days?

Comment: @EricDuminil I'd say the answers give the same result in different time zones.

Comment: @EricDuminil exactly, imagine a cron job running at / around midnight.

Answer (score 1):

This would work, although it's a bit hacky:

```
Time.at(Time.now.to_i % 86400)
#=> 1970-01-01 14:35:37 +0100
```

Note that [`Time.at`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Time.html#method-c-at) returns an instance in the local time zone.

Answer (score 0):

One way you could do this:

```
t = Time.now
#=> 2016-10-27 13:22:04 +0000
u = Time.at(0)
#=> 1970-01-01 00:00:00 +0000
hend_time = Time.new(u.year, u.month, u.day, t.hour, t.min, t.sec)
#=> 1970-01-01 13:22:04 +0000
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to do this automatically?

Are you asking if the Ruby `Time` class has method to return Epoch time (1970-01-01)?  Glancing through the `Time` documentation I found no instances to return the Epoch time (http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Time.html). You can easily create a `Time` instance that has the Epoch time though `Time.new('1970', '01', '01)`

Comment: `Time.at(0)` returns the Unix epoch, but the OP wants to keep the hours, minutes and seconds from the provided `Time.now` object.